# wordpress page php redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

im struggling to find a way to redirect a wordpress page to a random predefined list of url's.

Each URL is a sub domain of the original domain, so:

page1.homepage.com, page2.homepage.com, page3.homepage.com

I know this code should appear before the doctype which i've done.

Now for some reason i cant get it to work! Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    $urls           = array('http://1.home.com','http://2.home.com','http://3.home.com');
    $random_value   = array_rand($urls);
    $random_link    = $urls[$random_value];

    ("location: $random_link")
```

Comment: `header("Location: $random_link");` http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **wordpress** there is an built in **function** to do that ***wp_redirect***,

use it like this,

```
$urls = array(
    'http://1.home.com',
    'http://2.home.com',
    'http://3.home.com'
);
$random_value = array_rand($urls);
$random_link = $urls[$random_value];
wp_redirect($random_link, 301);
exit;
```

Reffer for more information [wp redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

Comment: Thanks, I've been pulling my hair out, I'm still learning lots and lots so a big thank you for your help!